# Enumerators in Ruby

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I'm having a trouble understanding Enumerators in Ruby.

Please correct me If I'm wrong, `o.enum_for(:arg)` method is supposed to convert object to Enumerator and every iteration over object `o` should call `arg` method?
What confuses me is how this line of code works

```
[4, 1, 2, 0].enum_for(:count).each_with_index do |elem, index|
  elem == index
end
```

It should count how many elements are equal to their position in the array, and it works. However, I don't understand what's actually going on. Is `each_with_index` calling count method on every iteration? If someone could explain, it would be great.

Comment: Actually no, block is executed 4 times, just test it in irb

Answer (score 3):

From Programming Ruby:

> **count**  *enum.count {| obj | block } → int*
>
> Returns the count of objects in enum that equal obj or for which the
>   block returns a true value.

So the enumerator visits each element and adds 1 to the count if the block returns true, which in this case means if the element is equal to the array index.

I haven't seen this pattern used much (if at all)—I would be more inclined to:

```
[4, 1, 2, 0].each_with_index.select { |elem, index| elem == index }.count
```

***EDIT***

Lets take a look at the example from your comment:

```
[4, 1, 2, 0].enum_for(:each_slice, 2).map do |a, b|
  a + b
end
```

`each_slice(2)` takes the array 2 elements at a time and returns an array for each slice:

```
[4, 1, 2, 0].each_slice(2).map # => [[4,1], [2,0]]
```

calling `map` on the result lets us operate on each sub-array, passing it into a block:

```
[4, 1, 2, 0].enum_for(:each_slice, 2).map do |a,b|
  puts "#{a.inspect} #{b.inspect}"
end
```

results in

```
4 1
2 0
```

`a` and `b` get their values by virtue of the block arguments being "splatted":

```
a, b = *[4, 1]
a # => 4
b # => 1
```

You could also take the array slice as the argument instead:

```
[4, 1, 2, 0].enum_for(:each_slice, 2).map {|a| puts "#{a.inspect}"}

[4, 1]
[2, 0]
```

Which lets you do this:

```
[4, 1, 2, 0].enum_for(:each_slice, 2).map {|a| a.inject(:+) } #=> [5,2]
```

Or if you have ActiveSupport (i.e. a Rails app),

```
[4, 1, 2, 0].enum_for(:each_slice, 2).map {|a| a.sum }
```

Which seems a lot clearer to me than the original example.

Comment: What confuses me really is where from  |elemen, index| get their values.In my first example it is from I guess each_with_index, but look at this code [4, 1, 2, 0].enum_for(:each_slice, 2).map do |a, b|
            a + b
 end, here, |a, b| get from each_slice...

Answer (score 0):

`array.count` can normally take a block, but on its own, it returns a fixnum, so it can't be chained to `.with_index` the way some other iterators can (try `array.map.with_index {|x,i ... }`, etc).

`.enum_for(:count)` converts it into a enumerator, which allows that chaining to take place. It iterates once over the members of array, and keeps a tally of how many of them equal their indexes. So count is really only being called once, but only after converting the array into something more flexible.